# objective c regex how to find string and returning contained line?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have a sample of tex just like this.I need objective c to find for example string "龜" and return all containing line

齶 737B U9f76 B211 S24 XJ15642 N5437 V7100 MN48725 MP12.1108 P1-15-9 I3d21.1 Q2672.7 Ye4 Wag ガク あご はぐき {jaw}

龕 737C U9f95 B9 C212 S22 N568 V7104 MN48839 MP12.1151 P2-2-20 I2a20.3 Q8021.1 Ykan1 Wgam カン ガン れい {alcove for an image}

龜 737D U9f9c B213 S18 S16 XJ03535 XH2147 XN5445 V7106 H2150 O2598A MN48847 MP12.1151 P2-2-16 I2n9.1 Q2711.7 ZPP4-18-4 Ygui1 Yjun1 Yqiu1 Wgwi Wgu Wgyun キ キュウ キン かめ T1 ひさし {turtle} {tortoise}

龠 737E U9fa0 B214 S17 N5446 V7107 H2149 MN48882 MP12.1159 P2-2-15 I2a15.5 Q8022.7 ZPP2-3-14 Yyue4 Wyag ヤク ふえ {flute}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` in with the `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` option (so that `^` and `$` will match the start and end of a line). You could use capturing parentheses, too, if you wanted, but they're not needed here.

Thus:

```
NSString *fullContent = @"齶 737B U9f76 B211 S24 XJ15642 N5437 V7100 MN48725 MP12.1108 P1-15-9 I3d21.1 Q2672.7 Ye4 Wag ガク あご はぐき {jaw}\n"
                         "龕 737C U9f95 B9 C212 S22 N568 V7104 MN48839 MP12.1151 P2-2-20 I2a20.3 Q8021.1 Ykan1 Wgam カン ガン れい {alcove for an image}\n"
                         "龜 737D U9f9c B213 S18 S16 XJ03535 XH2147 XN5445 V7106 H2150 O2598A MN48847 MP12.1151 P2-2-16 I2n9.1 Q2711.7 ZPP4-18-4 Ygui1 Yjun1 Yqiu1 Wgwi Wgu Wgyun キ キュウ キン かめ T1 ひさし {turtle} {tortoise}\n"
                         "龠 737E U9fa0 B214 S17 N5446 V7107 H2149 MN48882 MP12.1159 P2-2-15 I2a15.5 Q8022.7 ZPP2-3-14 Yyue4 Wyag ヤク ふえ {flute}";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^.*?龜.*?$" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:fullContent options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullContent length])];
if (match) {
    NSString *matchString = [fullContent substringWithRange:match.range];
    NSLog(@"%@", matchString);
}
```

The regex string `^.*?龜.*?$` translates to "find any line that contains this kanji character (龜) preceded by or followed by any sequence of characters." The `^` matches the start of the line (because of the `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` option). The `$` matches the end of the line. The `.*?` sequences match the shortest possible string of characters necessary to satisfy the rest of the regex.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked flawlessly though I am still trying to understand the code :)

Comment: I simplified regex a bit (the capturing parentheses were actually not needed) and tried to explain what I did.

Comment: thanks again by the way I've got another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257767/objective-c-regex-how-to-put-the-last-line-into-array

Comment: take a look if you can

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (not tested):

```
NSString *testStr = @"齶 737B U9f76 B211 S24 XJ15642 N5437 V7100 MN48725 MP12.1108 P1-15-9 I3d21.1 Q2672.7 Ye4 Wag ガク あご はぐき {jaw}

龕 737C U9f95 B9 C212 S22 N568 V7104 MN48839 MP12.1151 P2-2-20 I2a20.3 Q8021.1 Ykan1 Wgam カン ガン れい {alcove for an image}

龜 737D U9f9c B213 S18 S16 XJ03535 XH2147 XN5445 V7106 H2150 O2598A MN48847 MP12.1151 P2-2-16 I2n9.1 Q2711.7 ZPP4-18-4 Ygui1 Yjun1 Yqiu1 Wgwi Wgu Wgyun キ キュウ キン かめ T1 ひさし {turtle} {tortoise}

龠 737E U9fa0 B214 S17 N5446 V7107 H2149 MN48882 MP12.1159 P2-2-15 I2a15.5 Q8022.7 ZPP2-3-14 Yyue4 Wyag ヤク ふえ {flute}";

NSRegularExpression *pRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"龜.*" 
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

[pRegex enumerateMatchesInString:testStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testStr length]) 
usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *matches, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

// Do something with the matches found

}];
```