# objective C regex how to put the last line into array

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, macos, cocoa

if I have a sample line as below how to write regex in objective c to capture the last english meanings which enclosed in {} braces into array though they can be more than 3 meanings ie 4 braces or 5

龜 737D U9f9c B213 S18 S16 XJ03535 XH2147 XN5445 V7106 H2150 O2598A MN48847 MP12.1151 P2-2-16 I2n9.1 Q2711.7 ZPP4-18-4 Ygui1 Yjun1 Yqiu1 Wgwi Wgu Wgyun キ キュウ キン かめ T1 ひさし {turtle} {tortoise} {or}

Comment: Please add information on what you have tried and what isn't working

Comment: I have managed to implement it in php using 
preg_match_all("/\{[^\{^\}]*\}/", $rawKanjiInfo, $meaning);
but I couldn't understand the nsregularexpression because I am still new to objective C

Comment: I am very sorry for being not specific in my question cause I am still newbi and I ve got poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the capturing parentheses to capture everything in between the braces, but not including the braces:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[{]([^}]*)[}]" options:0 error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *found = [string substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", found);
}];
```